# R (Stratified) Random Sampling for Defined Cases

Tags: r, random, sampling

I have a **data frame**:

```
DF <- data.frame(Value = c("AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF", "FG", "GH", "HI", "IJ", "JK", "KL", "LM"),
                 ID    = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1))
```

My question: I would like to create a **new column** that includes a (binary) **random number** ('`0`' or '`1`') **for cases** `'ID' == 1` with a **fixed proportion** (or pre-defined prevalence) (e.g., random numbers '`0`' x 2 and '`1`' x 4).

**EDIT I:**
For non-case specific purposes, the solution might be:

```
DF$RANDOM[sample(1:nrow(DF), nrow(DF), FALSE)] <- rep(RANDOM, c(nrow(DF)-4,4))
```

But, I still need the cas-specific assignment AND the aforementioned solution does not explicitly refer to '`0`' or '`1`'.

(Note: The variable '`value`' is not relevant for the question; only an identifier.)

I figured out relevant posts on [stratified sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726614/stratified-random-sampling-in-r) or [random row selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273313/sample-random-rows-in-dataframe) - but this question is not covered by those (and other) posts.

Thank you VERY much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the data first by case `ID == 1`. To ensure occurrence of 1s and 0s, we use `rep` function and set `replace` to False in `sample` function.
Here's a solution.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(121)
DF[ID == 1, new_column := sample(rep(c(0,1), c(2,4)), .N, replace = F)]
print(DF1)

     Value ID new_column
 1:    AB  1          1
 2:    BC  0         NA
 3:    CD  0         NA
 4:    DE  1          1
 5:    EF  0         NA
 6:    FG  1          1
 7:    GH  1          1
 8:    HI  0         NA
 9:    IJ  0         NA
10:    JK  1          0
11:    KL  0         NA
12:    LM  1          0
```

Comment: Yes, I know. BUT: I require a solution without a prior subset AND you worked with probabilities (I need fixed proportions - no probabilities).

Comment: I've made few changes. After doing set.seed, the prob parameter will always generate the same number of 1s and 0s. Since you want to generate 1 and 0 randomly, such that 1 occurs 4 times and 0 should occur 2 times, that's how it's going to work.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the 'prob' part (you computed the proportion of  the provided numbers). But I would like to have the fix numbers. Finally, when you create an additional column (e.g., DF_1[ID == 1, new_column_additional := sample(c(0,1), .N, replace = T, prob = c(0.33,0.67))] ) the result is wrong.

Comment: I've added the fix by using rep instead of probabilities. Please check.

Comment: GREAT. This works as anticipated. Thanks for your fast replies and your help. Good solution.

Comment: Glad, I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(Value = c("AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF", "FG", "GH", 
                           "HI", "IJ", "JK", "KL", "LM"),
                 ID = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_n(4, replace = FALSE)
```

Comment: Your example does not work since you do not refer to the defined cases.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank. No, since your example is not case-specific.