# Stratified random sampling with no repeated IDs

Tags: r, random, sampling

I have a dataset where each `id` has multiple samples and can be stratified into `group` variable. I would like to do random sampling, stratified by `group`, but not have the `id` be repeated (i.e. each `id` only appears once in the output).

I have tried to modify some existing solutions, however, all seem to sample the data and include multiple samples from a single `id` across the groups:

- [random sampling - matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109778/random-sampling-matrix)
- [Stratified random sampling from data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479512/stratified-random-sampling-from-data-frame)
- [Stratified random sampling in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726614/stratified-random-sampling-in-r)
- [Stratified random sampling from data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479512/stratified-random-sampling-from-data-frame?rq=1)

I have tried the following, thinking `replace = FALSE` may help to ensure that only 1 sample from each `id` is used, but this still does not do what I want.

```
set.seed(1)
# Data 
data <- data.frame(
  id = c("A", "C", "B", "D", "E", "F", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F"),
  group = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "1", "3"),
  length = c("54", "52", "43", "42", "60", "46", "59", "60", "51", "45", "47", "58", "48", "46", "56", "57"))

# Stratified random sampling by group 
sample <- data %>%
  distinct %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  sample_n(2, replace = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(data)
```

`sample` output:

```
id group length
A   1   60      
C   1   52      
D   2   42      
A   2   59      
B   3   47      
E   3   60
```

However, as seen above, the **`id`= A** is repeated in **`group` 1 and 2**. The ideal output I would like should look something like this where each `id` appears only once and samples are stratified by `group`:

```
id group length
A   1   54      
C   1   52      
B   2   43      
D   2   42      
E   3   60      
F   3   46
```

Is there a way to customise the existing solutions so that when sampling for each `group`, if an `id` has already been used for another `group`, it will be excluded and not sampled for another `group`? I know I can add `%>% distinct(id)` to my code but I believe this would not be random anymore as `distinct()` just picks up the first row for that `id`. Thank you for any help!

Comment: If it is small and known number of groups, are you able to iterate over groups while keeping track of ids being sampled, so that when you go to next group, you do setdiff() before sampling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I used in the end.

```
# Randomise rows
set.seed(x) # play around and set seed accordingly
data_rows <- sample(nrow(data))
data2 <- data[data_rows, ]

# Stratified random sampling 
set.seed(x) # play around and set seed accordingly
randomised <- data2 %>%
              distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
              group_by(group) %>% 
              sample_n(2, replace = FALSE) %>%
              ungroup()
```

Comment: Definetly a neat solution! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have a candidate solution for you, using `for-loops`. Granted, the solution is a bit awkward, and has some caveats which are related to your provided data. However, the script works as intended.

```
# Split by group; this provides
# a list with each group.
data_list <- data %>% split(
        f = .$group
)

# shuffle the list to introduce
# randomness
shuffle <- sample(length(data_list))

data_list <- data_list[shuffle]

# Sample from the first indice
# which serves as a baseline for remaining
# samples
sampled_data <- data_list[[1]] %>%
        distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
        sample_n(2)


for (i in 2:length(data_list)) {
        
        # Proceed to next group
        new_data <- data_list[[i]]
        
        
        indicator <- new_data$id %in% sampled_data$id
        
        sampled_data <- bind_rows(
                sampled_data,
                new_data[!indicator,] %>% distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% group_by(group) %>% sample_n(2)
        )
        
        
        
}
```

This algorithm, with the `data` that you provided, works if the initial `sampled_data` has specific `ids` present as, otherwise, the availability of unique ids will deplete.

The algorithm starts by splitting your data in respective groups by using `split`, and shuffles the order of the `list` to introduce randomness in your `distinct` function.

**Initial Sampling**

We start by taking a `sample` from the first group, which then serves as a baseline for the remainder of the groups.

It starts by removing all `id` from the next indices that are present in the baseline sample. And then samples and binds that to the list, and creates a `data.frame`.

**Next Sample**

The new `data.frame` now consists of the first two groups that are distinct in `id`, and removes `id` from the remaining indice that are present in that `data.frame`.

End product is the following;

```
id group length
1  B     1     51
2  C     1     52
3  D     2     42
4  A     2     59
5  E     3     60
6  F     3     46
```

The algorithm, clearly, needs some polishing if the data you provided are representative for you actual data, as depending on the `seed` the availability of unique values depletes depending on your initial `id`.

I did not provide a `seed` as I had trouble finding one suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! The solution I used in the end had similar logic to your answer in that I first introduced randomisation. This was by `set.seed()` then randomising all rows using `data2 <- data[sample(nrow(data)),]`. Since now the rows were randomised, I could use `distinct()` without worrying about it picking only the first row for each `id`. Then I `set.seed()` again and used `data2` to run the remaining codes. The `seed` needed to be played around with so that the unique `id` would be maximised for the groups.

Comment: Quite a clever modification! :-) It was tough nut to crack honestly.

Comment: Can you accept the answer, so we know its closed then? Or do you expect more answers? :-)

Comment: I have added the solution I used in the end as the accepted answer. Thank you again for your solution, will be helpful when a looped version is required.

Comment: Nah - with `dplyr` and `group_by()` you'll hardly need a `for-loop`!